# Is there a way to split a list of objects into n number of lists depending on the number of unique values of an object field?

Tags: java, oop

I have a method that returns a list of objects.

In that object, there is a String field orderType.

Is there a way for me to separate that list into n number of lists depending on the unique values of orderType?

For example the method returns a list containing 10 objects, then 4 of them has orderType value of x, 3 has orderType value of y, then another 4 has a value of z.

then the result will be 3 lists containing 4,3,4 objects respectively

orderType does not only have x, y and z as possible values.

i am having a hard time putting this into an actual code but my idea is like this

```
List<Orders> orderList = getOrder();


for(int i=0; i<orderList.size();i++){

   if(orderList.get(i).orderType is unique){
        create a new list
   }else{
        add to an existing list having the same orderType
   }
}
```

Comment: please show a [mcve] and expected output

Comment: Please add some code, the output you are getting and the output you want.

Comment: Would you accept a map of `{"x":[obj, obj, obj], "y":[...], "z": [...]}`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer  yes, a map could work too

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this rather general function:

```
    public static <T, U> Map<U, List<T>> getLists(List<T> values, Function<T, U> orderBy) {
        Map<U, List<T>> lists = new HashMap<>();
        for (T value : values) {
            U type = orderBy.apply(value);
            if (!lists.containsKey(type)) {
                lists.put(type, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            lists.get(type).add(value);
        }
        return lists;
    }
```

Order Class:

```
class Order {

        private String orderType;
        private String name;

        public Order(String orderType, String name) {
            this.orderType = orderType;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getOrderType() {
            return orderType;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }
```

How to use:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE1", "Order1"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE2", "Order2"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE1", "Order3"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE1", "Order4"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE2", "Order5"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE1", "Order6"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE1", "Order7"));
        orders.add(new Order("TYPE1", "Order8"));

        Map<String, List<Order>> map =  getLists(orders, Order::getOrderType);

        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
            for (Order order : map.get(key)) {
                System.out.println(order.getOrderType() + " " + order.getName());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to pull out the element to a Map, then you can take advantage of the `Collectors.toMap` third parameter that combines the values of the same key.

```
public void tryIt() {
    // given
    class Foo {
        String x;

        Foo(String x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> {
        foos.add(new Foo("x"));
        foos.add(new Foo("z"));
    });
    IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> foos.add(new Foo("y")));

    // create a mapping of element, to list of original object, grouping by same element key
    Map<String, List<Foo>> collect = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            f -> f.x, 
            Collections::singletonList,
            (l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

Output

```
{x=[x, x, x, x], y=[y, y, y], z=[z, z, z, z]}
```

Comment: thanks man, I will try to understand the code first and try it later